# How to get a return from Android Room database select query using RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android, android-room

Here is my query

```
@Query("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM media2 WHERE path = :path AND isFav = 1 LIMIT 1)")
    int checkIsFav(String path);
```

Call from repository

```
public boolean checkIsFav(String path) {
    return mDatabase.favDAO().checkIsFav(path) == 1;
}
```

This causes the following error sometimes

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
```

I understand why but I need a return to be able to determine if item is a Fav.

I use RXjava for my other database actions but they do not require a return.

```
Observable.fromCallable(() -> mDatabase.favDAO().checkIsFav(path) == 1);
```

or

```
Observable.just(mDatabase)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribe(db -> db.favDAO().insertMedia2(media));
```

I am using this method in my fragment

```
if (mediaViewModel.checkIsFav(media.getPath())){
    mediaViewModel.removeFav(media.getPath());
} else {
    media.setFav(true);
    mediaViewModel.addFav(media);
}
```

and recycler adapter.

```
 boolean isfav = ((App)context.getApplicationContext()).getRepository()
     .checkIsFav(currentItem.getPath());
```

What is the easiest way to get my callback when running this query?

**Updated Question with Single:**

This is my query in my Dao

```
@Query("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM media2 WHERE path = :path AND isFav = 1 LIMIT 1)")
Single<Integer> checkIsFav(String path);
```

my method in repository

```
public Single<Integer> checkIsFav(String path){
    return mDatabase.favDAO().checkIsFav(path);
}
```

I need to make this call from my adapter and my fragment. how would i do that when to call it would look like this?

```java
((App)context.getApplicationContext()).getRepository().checkIsFav(media.getPath())
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(
        new SingleObserver<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Integer integer) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {

            }
        }
    );
```

That just doesn't seem right. before I converted to room this was my call

```
if (App.favDB.existFav(currentItem.getPath()))
```

Which triggered this in my SQLiteOpenHelper

```
 public boolean existFav(String path) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(
            String.format("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM %s WHERE %s=? LIMIT 1)", TABLE_NAME, MEDIA_PATH),
            new String[]{ path });
        boolean tracked = cur.moveToFirst() &&  cur.getInt(0) == 1;
        cur.close();
        return tracked;
    }
```

Maybe im not thinking this through properly.

All I am trying to do is to determine whether this media exists in my table.

Comment: If you want to read on the UI thread, then you can add the `allowMainThreadQueries` to the Room builder. Of course, it blocks this by default for a reason.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should observe your data in the main thread. so use

```
observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).
```

try to change it to

```
Observable.just(mDatabase)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) 
        .subscribe(db -> db.favDAO().insertMedia2(media));
```

also see this [notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48339584/rxjava2-subscribeon-observeon-confusion-running-on-main-thread/48340240#48340240) on `observeOn()`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
@Query("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM media2 WHERE path = :path AND isFav = 1 LIMIT 1)")
int checkIsFav(String path);
```

to:

```
@Query("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM media2 WHERE path = :path AND isFav = 1 LIMIT 1)")
Single<Integer> checkIsFav(String path);
```

Using [RxJava with Room](https://medium.com/google-developers/room-rxjava-acb0cd4f3757) works, though I have not tried it with `SELECT EXISTS`, and so YMMV.

Comment: but how do I actually do the callback to get the single? what does that look like?

Comment: @Bignadad: Um, that's just a method on your DAO. `Single` is one of the RxJava `Observable` types, so you just set up a chain to act upon the value (e.g., `subscribeOn()`, `observeOn()`). So, `dao.checkIsFav(path).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(...)`.

Comment: I updated my question. please tell me if im thinking of this wrong.

Comment: @Bignadad: "before I converted to room this was my call" -- hopefully, that is not the case. That would imply that you were doing database I/O on the main application thread.

Comment: Yes it is but its not been published yet. But I don't have any issues making that call. Im reading through you book now (i have a subscription) trying to make sense of it.

Comment: @Bignadad: The reason why your old code is simpler than the new code is because you are dealing with threading in the new code, and you are not in the old code. As the saying goes, "you are comparing apples and oranges".

Answer (score 0):

You should add to your build.gradle

implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:version'

As for how each type behaves, check out this medium post https://medium.com/google-developers/room-rxjava-acb0cd4f3757

Answer (score 0):

Eh, you were always reading this on the UI thread before. Now Room enforces by default that you shouldn't do that because it can potentially block the UI thread.

If you don't feel like caring about this restriction and just want your old type of code to work, you can use [RoomDatabase.Builder's allowMainThreadQueries()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/RoomDatabase.Builder.html#allowMainThreadQueries())

Otherwise, just expose Flowable and subscribe on Io, observe on Ui like you normally would.

Answer (score 0):

We could create Single like this:

```java
public Single<SomeObject> getSomeObjectFromDB(Session session) {
    return createAsyncSingle(() -> database.getSomeDao().getSomeObject())
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) // We can move it on upper level;
}
```

Where:

```java
protected <T> Single<T> createAsyncSingle(final Callable<T> func) {
    return Single.create(emitter -> {
        try {
            T result = func.call();
            if(result != null) {
                emitter.onSuccess(result);
            } else {
                emitter.onError(new NullPointerException("Empty result from DB"));
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.e("TAG", "Error operation with DB");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A little late for the question asked, but hoping to help anyone implementing one-shot read queries in Room with RXJava.

1. Define your query in the DAO:

```
    @Query("SELECT id, name, lastName FROM Students WHERE age = :age")
     Single<List<Students_Schema>> selectStudents(int age);
```

2. To access the values use blockingGet().

```
    result = student_DB.student_dao().selectStudents(age);
result.blockingGet().get(0).name;
```

This is a great guide about accessing Single:

https://medium.com/@katcri/ways-to-handle-what-your-rxjava-single-is-emitting-2f3e335b8f41