# Emit values on the thread that chain is subscribed to

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, rx-java2

#### Problem

I'm facing an issue when trying to use a BroadcastReceiver within an Observer.

The emitted items by the BroadcastReceiver are being emitted on the main thread, instead of the thread that is passed on `subscribeOn`.

#### Code - actual scenario

For example, given the code below, which is nearly identical to the RxBroadcastReceiver class from this [link](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/4937):

```
public static final class RxBroadcastReceiver implements ObservableOnSubscribe<String> {
    public static Observable<String> create(Context context, IntentFilter intentFilter) {
        return Observable.create(new RxBroadcastReceiver(context, intentFilter));
    }

    private final Context context;
    private final IntentFilter intentFilter;

    private RxBroadcastReceiver(Context context, IntentFilter intentFilter) {
        this.context = context;
        this.intentFilter = intentFilter;
    }

    @Override
    public void subscribe(final ObservableEmitter<String> emitter) throws Exception {
        final BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
                emitter.onNext(threadName);
            }
        };
        context.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
        emitter.setDisposable(Disposables.fromRunnable(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                context.unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
            }
        }));
    }
}
```

When the following code is run:

```
RxBroadcastReceiver.create(context, filter)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe(new Consumer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(final String executedThread) throws Exception {
            String acceptedThread = Thread.currentThread().getName();

            System.out.println("executedThread: " + executedThread);
            System.out.println("acceptedThread: " + acceptedThread);
        }
    });
```

The output shows that the executed thread was the main thread and not the thread from Schedulers.io:

```
executedThread: main
acceptedThread: main
```

#### Code - expected results

Whereas if the code below is used:

```
public static final class RxJavaBroadcaster implements ObservableOnSubscribe<String> {
    public static Observable<String> create() {
        return Observable.create(new RxJavaBroadcaster());
    }

    @Override
    public void subscribe(final ObservableEmitter<String> emitter) throws Exception {
        String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        emitter.onNext(threadName);
    }
}
```

When the following code is run:

```
RxJavaBroadcaster.create()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe(new Consumer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(final String executedThread) throws Exception {
            String acceptedThread = Thread.currentThread().getName();

            System.out.println("executedThread: " + executedThread);
            System.out.println("acceptedThread: " + acceptedThread);
        }
    });
```

The output is, as expected, not in the main thread:

```
executedThread: RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
acceptedThread: RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
```

#### Research

The reason why I think the items are being emitted on the main thread is because [BroadcastReceiver.onReceive](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive(android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent)) is always called within the main thread of its process.

Given that the above correct, an alternative solution that I can think of, would be to register the BroadcastReceiver passing a custom Handler with this [method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Handler)).

Then my questions are:

1. How can the correct `Scheduler` that was passed to `subscribeOn` be retrieved from RxBroadcastReceiver?
2. How can create a [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler) bound to that specific Scheduler?

Does anyone see a different alternative?

My problem is exactly the same as described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35554181/observable-runs-on-main-thread-even-though-subscribeon-is-called-on-another-th) and in fact I'm already using the solution proposed there (call a second subscribeOn) but I would prefer a different alternative.

Comment: Your rationale over the called thread for `onReceive` is correct - do you need both provider and consumer on a RxScheduler? If you require just the consumer then just change `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` to `.observeOn(Schedulers.io())` in your original example

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to emit on specific Scheduler and accept on main thread. I think your solution will be using RxAndroid 
https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid

Change code from expected results to use `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())`

```
RxJavaBroadcaster.create()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new Consumer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(final String executedThread) throws Exception {
            String acceptedThread = Thread.currentThread().getName();

            System.out.println("executedThread: " + executedThread);
            System.out.println("acceptedThread: " + acceptedThread);
        }
    });
```

Comment: No, my problem is not to observeOn the main thread, in fact I'm already doing it with RxAndroid. The problem is that the value emitted by RxBroadcastReceiver at line `emitter.onNext(threadName);` is done on the main thread instead of IO thread, after explicitly calling `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())`